# decoding a JSON $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, http-post

ok I will try this again, asked multiple times but don't seem to be making myself clear.

First I have an AJAX script running on a webpage that allows me to extract data from a game.

This data is then sent to a PHP 'api' page using a POST method.

I can see in the console of my browser that the data is actually going.

Here is the data stream sample: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FLHiWBSBqqm7N8LvzISmiedQKxsqYM572iAT4CQpjP8/edit?usp=sharing

Now here is my problem:

I can see the data is being parsed to the PHP. The PHP code is below:

```
<?php
        // set headers for API
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
        header('Content-type: application/json');


$m = false;

if(preg_match('/http\:\/\/prodgame([0-9]+)\.lordofultima\.com/',$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'],$m))
    { $m = $m[1]; }

if(empty($m)) { die('Invalid Origin.'); }

if(!empty($_POST['data_type']))
        {
        $sender     = $_POST['sender'];
        $alliance   = $_POST['alliance'];
        $request    = $_POST['data_type'];
        $data       = $_POST['data'];

        // Response to Alliance Info Exporter
        $json       = array(
            'message'   => 'recieved.',
            'data'      => array(),
            'error'     => false
        );

        // handle data types

        switch($request)
            {
            case 'connection_test': $json['message'] = 'Welcome to our server2. Your are connected!'; break;
            case 'member'   : /* Code for member request */         break;
            case 'city' :   /* Code for member request */ break;
            case 'support'  : /* Code for support request */        break;
            default         :  $json['message'] = 'Nothing Done.';  break;
            }



        // Respond
        die(json_encode($json));
        }
die('No Access.');

?>
```

The data is being parsed from the .js file that I run locally while I playing this online game.  The creator has posted the PHP example, obviously intending whoever uses it to add their required code to the switch/case statement to manipulate the data.

Now, I tried as a test just to extract the data using json_decode with various options ($_POST, or $POST('data' or the variables as defined in PHP), just to validate the data. Nothing works.

var_dump doesn't work for me because the client js does is such that I cannot modify the code on the server side PHP from what is provided - the client looks for a response before I can trigger the send to server function.

What could I be doing wrong. As you can see from the HTML POST output in the google link data *is* being transferred. How do I access and manipulate this data?  My end goal is to parse the data as it comes into an SQL database, but I need to be sure of handling it first.

my environment - right now in dev I am using a local machine, PHP on Apache running on a Linux OS. I also have mySql loaded but not in play right now. All most recent versions, just installed dev environment yesterday.

Some more information - I tried inserting this code in the case statement as well as earlier in the document, and the best output I have got using this or var_export is a 0 byte file or  a file that just says NULL:

```
$data1 = json_decode($_POST, $assoc = null);
$f = fopen("/var/www/aix/data/alliance6.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $data1);
fclose($f);
```

Another bit of information - from what I can make out the send to server function in the javascript is called as follows:

```
// send to server
req = main.ajax.send({
alliance : {
    id : a.id,
    name : a.name,
    members : a.members,
    score : a.total_score                                       
},
data_type:type,
data:json
});                 
if(req){
req.success(function(x){
main.aix.set_loading(tab.index,"Data sent to server!",1000);
main.aix.get_saved(id,type).sent = true;

});
}
});
}
else
{ main.aix.set_loading(tab.index,"This data has already been sent.",2000); }
}
if(typeof callback == "function")
{ callback(json); }
}
},
```

So an update to this above: the echo command provided by Wayne below does indeed give me the  data structure for the $data variable. Now a follow up question: How do I transpose all the data I am getting (sender, data arrray, etc) into a SQL table? And in the event of updating/refreshing the tables I create on a regular basis, how would I deduplicate the data in the database?

Comment: Have you done a var_dump on the $data array?

Comment: I've tried to, but shooting in the dark eere a bit. If I change the PHP and it doesn't send data back to the client, then I can run the export to test so catch 22.

Comment: It wont sent data back to the client because any output will break the outputted JSON. If you're doing a var_dump, it should only be for debugging purposes.

Comment: For these situations I temporarily change the method to GET in order to see what is, and is not, being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've confused yourself a little. You're trying to decode POST variables that aren't encoded in JSON. The JSON is outputted at the end of your script:

```
// Respond
die(json_encode($json));
```

Basically, you're worrying about JSON, even though your script doesn't deal with JSON until it is dumping it out onto the page when all of the processing is complete.

If you're looking to manipulate the incoming data, you should look more closely at the $data array:

```
$sender     = $_POST['sender'];
$alliance   = $_POST['alliance'];
$request    = $_POST['data_type'];
$data       = $_POST['data'];
```

By the way, judging from the POST data that you linked, $data will be a multi dimensional array.

Do the following and you should see what kind of structure you're dealing with:

```
$sender     = $_POST['sender'];
$alliance   = $_POST['alliance'];
$request    = $_POST['data_type'];
$data       = $_POST['data'];

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($data);
echo '</pre>;
```

Or try this:

```
foreach($data as $dataInfo){
    foreach($dataInfo as $key => $info){
        echo $key . ': ' . $info . '<br>';
    }
    echo '<hr>';
}
```

Comment: trying the second one gets me this back in the console window of my browser just posting a few records here:
id: 10879179<br>owner_id: 140<br>owner: player1<br>coords: '203:166<br>name: N23_00A<br>score: 11580<br>city_type: castle<br>location: water<br><hr>id: 10682590<br>owner_id: 140<br>owner: player1<br>coords: '222:163<br>name: C23_0AC<br>score: 11425<br>city_type: castle<br>location: land<br><hr>id: 10748124<br>owner_id: 140<br>owner: robwiz<br>coords: '220:164<br>name: C23_0AM<br>score: 10580<br>city_type: castle<br>location: land<br><hr>

Comment: thanks, now I have a full output dump of what structure I am dealing with. played around with it so I have a smaller dataset so I could pull everything. $log_to_file = print_r($_POST,$return=true);
     $f = fopen("/var/www/aix/data/member.txt", "w");
     fwrite($f, $log_to_file);
     fclose($f);
     echo $log_to_file;

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you question right you can't read the $_POST[]. Are you sure that the javascript is sending correct data? if no i would use jquery :

```
$.post("script.php",$("#FormForExample").serialize());
```

this will send the correct data. If this is not your question please excuse me.

Comment: You are correct  I can't read the $POST[]. However I am reasonably sure that the jquery is fine, because the PHP does recognise data coming through and send a success message back to the client.  I don't have much documentation on the javascript since the creator didn't comment the code in the javascript, but I will have a look.  The way the javascript is set up, I have to enter the destination PHP address in a client window, so it is dynamic. There is no static link to the PHP file in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this worked nicely after some experimentation

```
$log_to_file = print_r($_POST,$return=true);
$f = fopen("/var/www/aix/data/member.txt", "w");
fwrite($f, $log_to_file);
fclose($f);
```

By running this and using a known smaller dataset I was able to extract the full structure of the array(s) that were being parsed.  I had to use a smaller dataset because print_r() has a buffer of lines that it returns, after which it cuts off. I am sure there is a way around that, but I got what I needed for now, so will have to hold off further experimentation.

```
Array
(
    [alliance] => Array
        (
            [id] => 134
            [name] => Alliance1
            [members] => 9
            [score] => 17187
        )

    [data_type] => city
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16515340
                    [owner_id] => 3475
                    [owner] => Player1
                    [coords] => '268:252
                    [name] => AC2013
                    [score] => 11863
                    [city_type] => castle
                    [location] => land
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 16515335
                    [owner_id] => 3475
                    [owner] => Player1
                    [coords] => '263:252
                    [name] => AC2013
                    [score] => 7
                    [city_type] => castle
                    [location] => water
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17891610
                    [owner_id] => 3523
                    [owner] => Player2
                    [coords] => '282:273
                    [name] => City of Repoman9900
                    [score] => 1978
                    [city_type] => castle
                    [location] => water
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10616856
                    [owner_id] => 73
                    [owner] => Player2
                    [coords] => '024:162
                    [name] => 1killer
                    [score] => 1308
                    [city_type] => castle
                    [location] => water
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10813465
                    [owner_id] => 2862
                    [owner] => Player3
                    [coords] => '025:165
                    [name] => City of vuvuzea991
                    [score] => 1091
                    [city_type] => castle
                    [location] => land
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 17367317
                    [owner_id] => 84
                    [owner] => Player4
                    [coords] => '277:265
                    [name] => Dreadland
                    [score] => 776
                    [city_type] => castle
                    [location] => water
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2162850
                    [owner_id] => 2989
                    [owner] => Player5
                    [coords] => '162:033
                    [name] => City of Dinoeyez
                    [score] => 157
                    [city_type] => castle
                    [location] => water
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2818192
                    [owner_id] => 556
                    [owner] => Player6
                    [coords] => '144:043
                    [name] => City of wildfire123
                    [score] => 7
                    [city_type] => castle
                    [location] => water
                )

        )

    [sender] => Array
        (
            [world] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 232
                    [name] => Server 4 
                    [number] => NaN
                )

            [alliance] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Alliance2
                )

            [player] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 98
                    [name] => SuperUser
                )

            [browser] => Array
                (
                    [type] => Chrome
                    [version] => 25.0.1364.160
                )

            [aix_version] => 1.00
        )

)
```